# Cassandra polymorphism

Tags: cassandra, polymorphism

How can I do in Cassandra polymorphism?
For example, as shown below store json?
The first type, when the attachments added photos

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "Hello",
  "read": true,
  "attachment_type": 1,
  "attachment": {
    "photo_id": 1,
    "photo_big_url": "htt://photo.com/1_big.jpg",
    "photo_medium_url": "htt://photo.com/1_medium.jpg",
    "photo_small_url": "htt://photo.com/1_small.jpg"
  }
}
```

And the second type, when the attachments added videos

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "text": "Hi",
  "read": true,
  "attachment_type": 2,
  "attachment": {
    "video_id": 1,
    "video_url": "htt://video.com/1.mpg",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can combine your fields in a single Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE media (
  id int,
  name text,
  read boolean,
  attachment_type int,
  photo_id int,
  photo_big_url text,
  photo_medium_url text,
  photo_small_url" text,
  video_id int,
  video_url text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id), attachment_type)
);
```

Fields that are not completed are not stored in Cassandra, so you are not wasting hard disk space.

Depending on the driver you are using, you can declare different entities for Photo and Video, each having only the relevant fields, and map your results to entities accordingly.

With the DataStax driver for C# it would be something like:

```
mapper.Fetch<Photo>("SELECT * FROM media WHERE id = 1 and attachment_type = 1");
mapper.Fetch<Video>("SELECT * FROM media WHERE id = 1 and attachment_type = 2");
```

Comment: there is also the possibility of implementing this task except use single table?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question. Can you reformulate and give some examples?